# GridViewDataComboBoxColumn in ASPxGridView does not bind to EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an `ASPxGridView` bound to an `EntityDataSource`. One of my columns needs to reference a column from another entity, so I decided to make it a `GridViewDataComboBoxColumn`. My .aspx code is the following:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridDocumente" runat="server" DataSourceID="EDS" KeyFieldName="IDDocument" OnDataBinding="gridDocumente_DataBinding" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Theme="Moderno">
    <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
    <SettingsSearchPanel Visible="True" />
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowUpdateButton="true" VisibleIndex="0" ShowClearFilterButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True"></dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="IDDocument" VisibleIndex="1" Visible="false"><EditFormSettings Visible="False" /></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="NrInregistrare" VisibleIndex="2"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="DataInregistrare" VisibleIndex="3"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="TipD" VisibleIndex="4"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="NumeDocument" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Descriere" VisibleIndex="6"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="TipDocument" VisibleIndex="7">
            <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="EDSTipDocument" ValueField="IDTipDocument"  TextField="NumeTipDocument" ValueType="System.Int32"></PropertiesComboBox>
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<ef:EntityDataSource ID="EDSTipDocument" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Users.Models.DocumentContext" EntitySetName="TipuriDocumente" OnContextCreating="EDS_ContextCreating"></ef:EntityDataSource>
<ef:EntityDataSource ID="EDS" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Users.Models.DocumentContext" EntitySetName="Documente" EnableDelete="true" EnableUpdate="true" OnContextCreating="EDS_ContextCreating"></ef:EntityDataSource>
```

Although I have tried to follow the examples found on the Internet, the `GridViewDataComboBoxColumn` will not bind to `EDSTipDocument` datasource, it shows nothing in the grid.

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you verified that your EDSTipDocument data source actually returns values (e.g., via the SmartTag wizard)?

Comment: Do you have access to the EDSTipDocument entity from your code behind?  EDSTipDocument is a list of your entity right? I've only had success using code behind as well.  Try reading this and see if it gets you any farther.  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1351